# How can I find, xargs and grep the resulting output?

Tags: command-line, grep, find, xargs, pylint

I would like to check the 'code rating' for each Python file in a directory. The name of the file and its rating should be printed.

I thought the following would at least print all code ratings:

```
find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 pylint  | grep "has been rated"
```

However, it prints only one code rating. Why? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec pylint {} \; | grep "has been rated"
```

Comment: And how can I additinally print to name of the file?

Comment: find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \; | egrep 'py$|has been rated'